# Creating complex tables in Latex

Tags: tables

I'm transfering a project document to Latex. But I encounter one difficulty. There is a complex table in it and I really would not know how to remake this one in Latex. Could you guys give some help? The following table needs to be built in Latex:

[image: Complex table]

Tnx in advance.

Comment: You did not put any efforts in this question. Why should somebody help you? However, you seem to be proficient with WYSIWYG software. This LibreOffice plugin for calc might make your life much easier: http://www.ooowiki.de/Calc2LaTeX.html

Comment: You can start from here: [LaTeX/Tables/Spanning in both directions simultaneously](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Spanning_in_both_directions_simultaneously). That table is identical to yours, except maybe a couple of extra rows/columns.

Comment: Tnx for your comment, yeah I saw that link as well. Busy with fitting it to my situation right now.

Comment: It is fixed now. Maybe I shouldn't ask things that quickly anymore. Either way, tnx for your comments and making me aware of it!

Comment: @user2237168 You can post the solution as an answer by the way. You could help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
{
\centering
\captionof{table}{Play pattern}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
\cline{3-7} & & \multicolumn{5}{ c| } {Rounds} \\ 
\cline{3-7} & & 1.Round & 2.Round & 3.Round & 4.Round & 5.Round\\ 
\cline{1-7} \multicolumn{1}{ |c }{\multirow{5}{*}{Phases} } & \multicolumn{1}{  |c| }{1. Phase: Taking a Pic} & Mary & Stanley & Mary & Stanley & ...\\ 
 \cline{2-7} \multicolumn{1}{ |c }{} & \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{2. Phase: Naming the Object} & Mary & Stanley & Mary & Stanley & ...\\
 \cline{2-7} \multicolumn{1}{ |c }{} & \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{3. Making the Puzzle} & System & System & System & System & ...\\ 
 \cline{2-7} \multicolumn{1}{ |c }{} & \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{4. Phase: Guessing... (Getting Clues)} & Stanley & Mary & Stanley & Mary & ...\\
 \cline{2-7} \multicolumn{1}{ |c }{} & \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{5. Round Resolution} & System & System & System & System & ...\\
 \cline{1-7}
 \cline{2-7}
 \cline{4-7}\\
 \end{tabular}
 }
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that it keeps throwing errors about the caption2 package saying that it has become obsolete, which is strange because I am using only the caption package: Package caption Error: You can't use both, the (obsolete) caption2 *and*
(caption)                the (current) caption package.

Comment: Show us your preamble